# When I use `budo index_editor_java_02.js --open --live` everytime I see same thing .see already what was in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, budo

When I use `budo index_editor_java_02.js --open --live` every time I see same thing ,even I changed `index_editor_java_02.js` nothing happen and I see already what was in the browser at  `http://192.168.5.10:9966/` before.

so How should I changed the js file makes changes in browser

my result of budo command is :

```
[0002] info  Server running at http://192.168.5.10:9966/ (connect)
[0002] info  LiveReload running on 35729
[0003] 115ms       10KB (browserify)
[0013] 49ms          0B GET    304 /
[0013] 42ms       2540B GET    200 /css/main.css
[0013] 4ms        3163B GET    200 /css/light.css
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/three.min.js
[0013] 0ms        1497B GET    200 /js/libs/system.min.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/react-lite.min.js
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /ui-builder/react/core.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/controls/EditorControls.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/controls/TransformControls.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/jszip.min.js
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/AMFLoader.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/AWDLoader.js
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/BabylonLoader.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/ColladaLoader2.js
[0013] 3ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/FBXLoader.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/KMZLoader.js
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/MD2Loader.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/OBJLoader.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/PlayCanvasLoader.js
[0013] 5ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/PLYLoader.js
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/STLLoader.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/TGALoader.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/UTF8Loader.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/VRMLLoader.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/VTKLoader.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/ctm/lzma.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/ctm/ctm.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/ctm/CTMLoader.js
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/deprecated/SceneLoader.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/renderers/Projector.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js
[0013] 2ms           0B GET    304 /js/renderers/RaytracingRenderer.js
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/renderers/SoftwareRenderer.js
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/renderers/SVGRenderer.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/codemirror.css
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/theme/monokai.css
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/codemirror.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/mode/javascript.js
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/mode/glsl.js
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/esprima.js
[0013] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/jsonlint.js
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/glslprep.min.js
[0013] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/dialog.css
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/show-hint.css
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/tern.css
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/dialog.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/show-hint.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/tern.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/acorn/acorn.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/acorn/acorn_loose.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/acorn/walk.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/polyfill.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/signal.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/tern.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/def.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/comment.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/infer.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/doc_comment.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/tern-threejs/threejs.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/signals.min.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ui.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ui.three.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /dgframe/index.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/app.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Player.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Script.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/effects/VREffect.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/controls/VRControls.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/controls/OrbitControls.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/vr/WebVR.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Storage.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Editor.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Config.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/History.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Loader.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.File.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.Edit.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.Add.js
[0014] 2ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.Play.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.View.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.Help.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.Status.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Scene.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Project.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Data.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Settings.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Properties.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Object.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.Geometry.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.BufferGeometry.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.Modifiers.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.BoxGeometry.js
[0014] 2ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.CircleGeometry.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.CylinderGeometry.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.IcosahedronGeometry.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.PlaneGeometry.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.SphereGeometry.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.TorusGeometry.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.TorusKnotGeometry.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/geometries/TeapotBufferGeometry.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.TeapotBufferGeometry.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.LatheGeometry.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Material.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Animation.js
[0014] 3ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Script.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.GlobalScripts.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.History.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Toolbar.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Viewport.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Viewport.Info.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Command.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/AddObjectCommand.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/RemoveObjectCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/MoveObjectCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetPositionCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetRotationCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetScaleCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetValueCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetUuidCommand.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetColorCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetGeometryCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetGeometryValueCommand.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/MultiCmdsCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/AddScriptCommand.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/RemoveScriptCommand.js
[0014] 2ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetScriptValueCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetMaterialCommand.js
[0014] 8ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetMaterialValueCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetMaterialColorCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetMaterialMapCommand.js
[0014] 2ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetSceneCommand.js
[0014] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/html2canvas.js
[0014] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/three.html.js
[0014] 0ms        3163B GET    200 /css/light.css
[0036] 9ms         14KB GET    200 /
[0036] 4ms        2540B GET    200 /css/main.css
[0036] 6ms        3163B GET    200 /css/light.css
[0036] 1ms        1497B GET    200 /js/libs/system.min.js
[0036] 4ms         18KB GET    200 /js/libs/react-lite.min.js
[0036] 6ms        3446B GET    200 /ui-builder/react/core.js
[0036] 6ms        1951B GET    200 /js/libs/codemirror/theme/monokai.css
[0036] 14ms       8475B GET    200 /js/libs/codemirror/codemirror.css
[0036] 14ms        700B GET    200 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/show-hint.css
[0036] 17ms       1938B GET    200 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/tern.css
[0036] 14ms        539B GET    200 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/dialog.css
[0036] 9ms        485KB GET    200 /js/libs/three.min.js
[0036] 4ms        8495B GET    200 /js/controls/EditorControls.js
[0036] 7ms         34KB GET    200 /js/controls/TransformControls.js
[0036] 14ms        11KB GET    200 /js/loaders/AMFLoader.js
[0036] 22ms        25KB GET    200 /js/loaders/AWDLoader.js
[0036] 14ms        76KB GET    200 /js/libs/jszip.min.js
[0036] 8ms        5037B GET    200 /js/loaders/BabylonLoader.js
[0036] 13ms        32KB GET    200 /js/loaders/ColladaLoader2.js
[0036] 17ms        36KB GET    200 /js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js
[0036] 19ms        952B GET    200 /js/loaders/KMZLoader.js
[0036] 23ms        11KB GET    200 /js/loaders/MD2Loader.js
[0036] 17ms        61KB GET    200 /js/loaders/FBXLoader.js
[0037] 20ms        20KB GET    200 /js/loaders/OBJLoader.js
[0037] 25ms       3226B GET    200 /js/loaders/PlayCanvasLoader.js
[0037] 13ms        11KB GET    200 /js/loaders/PLYLoader.js
[0037] 13ms        12KB GET    200 /js/loaders/STLLoader.js
[0037] 18ms        12KB GET    200 /js/loaders/TGALoader.js
[0037] 19ms        19KB GET    200 /js/loaders/UTF8Loader.js
[0037] 15ms        24KB GET    200 /js/loaders/VRMLLoader.js
[0037] 17ms        26KB GET    200 /js/loaders/VTKLoader.js
[0037] 13ms        13KB GET    200 /js/loaders/ctm/lzma.js
[0037] 14ms       5468B GET    200 /js/loaders/ctm/CTMLoader.js
[0037] 18ms        25KB GET    200 /js/loaders/deprecated/SceneLoader.js
[0037] 14ms        18KB GET    200 /js/loaders/ctm/ctm.js
[0037] 16ms        22KB GET    200 /js/renderers/Projector.js
[0037] 22ms        13KB GET    200 /js/renderers/RaytracingRenderer.js
[0037] 21ms        26KB GET    200 /js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js
[0037] 15ms        34KB GET    200 /js/renderers/SoftwareRenderer.js
[0037] 18ms        12KB GET    200 /js/renderers/SVGRenderer.js
[0037] 12ms        29KB GET    200 /js/libs/codemirror/mode/javascript.js
[0037] 11ms       9043B GET    200 /js/libs/codemirror/mode/glsl.js
[0037] 12ms        18KB GET    200 /js/libs/jsonlint.js
[0037] 8ms        5095B GET    200 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/dialog.js
[0037] 14ms       138KB GET    200 /js/libs/esprima.js
[0037] 18ms       363KB GET    200 /js/libs/codemirror/codemirror.js
[0037] 17ms        15KB GET    200 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/show-hint.js
[0037] 18ms        25KB GET    200 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/tern.js
[0037] 14ms        44KB GET    200 /js/libs/acorn/acorn_loose.js
[0037] 15ms        12KB GET    200 /js/libs/acorn/walk.js
[0037] 18ms       9520B GET    200 /js/libs/ternjs/polyfill.js
[0037] 15ms        989B GET    200 /js/libs/ternjs/signal.js
[0037] 23ms       115KB GET    200 /js/libs/acorn/acorn.js
[0037] 16ms        36KB GET    200 /js/libs/ternjs/tern.js
[0037] 4ms         21KB GET    200 /js/libs/ternjs/def.js
[0037] 9ms         58KB GET    200 /js/libs/ternjs/infer.js
[0037] 10ms       2978B GET    200 /js/libs/ternjs/comment.js
[0037] 6ms         15KB GET    200 /js/libs/ternjs/doc_comment.js
[0037] 19ms       3107B GET    200 /js/libs/signals.min.js
[0037] 13ms        20KB GET    200 /js/libs/ui.js
[0037] 12ms       9287B GET    200 /js/libs/ui.three.js
[0037] 14ms       279KB GET    200 /js/libs/tern-threejs/threejs.js
[0037] 13ms       7179B GET    200 /dgframe/index.js
[0037] 14ms        860B GET    200 /js/Player.js
[0037] 15ms       7586B GET    200 /js/libs/app.js
[0037] 17ms       9767B GET    200 /js/Script.js
[0037] 10ms        12KB GET    200 /js/effects/VREffect.js
[0037] 11ms       3007B GET    200 /js/controls/VRControls.js
[0037] 16ms        23KB GET    200 /js/controls/OrbitControls.js
[0037] 12ms       2507B GET    200 /js/vr/WebVR.js
[0037] 14ms       2203B GET    200 /js/Storage.js
[0037] 5ms        1611B GET    200 /js/Config.js
[0037] 13ms        10KB GET    200 /js/Editor.js
[0037] 6ms        6536B GET    200 /js/History.js
[0037] 11ms        12KB GET    200 /js/Loader.js
[0037] 12ms        573B GET    200 /js/Menubar.js
[0037] 17ms       5554B GET    200 /js/Menubar.File.js
[0037] 8ms        3941B GET    200 /js/Menubar.Edit.js
[0037] 11ms        10KB GET    200 /js/Menubar.Add.js
[0037] 14ms        655B GET    200 /js/Menubar.Play.js
[0037] 10ms        726B GET    200 /js/Menubar.View.js
[0037] 11ms       1250B GET    200 /js/Menubar.Help.js
[0037] 6ms         930B GET    200 /js/Menubar.Status.js
[0037] 8ms        1638B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.js
[0037] 12ms       5636B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Scene.js
[0037] 14ms       5596B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Project.js
[0037] 7ms         906B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Settings.js
[0037] 11ms       6606B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Data.js
[0037] 5ms        1524B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Properties.js
[0037] 6ms         18KB GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Object.js
[0037] 14ms       4314B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.js
[0037] 17ms       1157B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.Geometry.js
[0037] 8ms         693B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.Modifiers.js
[0037] 10ms       1298B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.BufferGeometry.js
[0037] 10ms       2351B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.BoxGeometry.js
[0037] 6ms        1689B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.CircleGeometry.js
[0037] 12ms       2425B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.CylinderGeometry.js
[0037] 14ms       1111B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.IcosahedronGeometry.js
[0037] 13ms       1743B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.PlaneGeometry.js
[0037] 15ms       2695B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.SphereGeometry.js
[0037] 17ms       1988B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.TorusGeometry.js
[0037] 13ms       2195B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.TorusKnotGeometry.js
[0037] 13ms        19KB GET    200 /js/geometries/TeapotBufferGeometry.js
[0037] 18ms       3347B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.LatheGeometry.js
[0037] 21ms       2281B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.TeapotBufferGeometry.js
[0037] 17ms        34KB GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Material.js
[0037] 13ms       2433B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Animation.js
[0037] 6ms        2611B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.Script.js
[0037] 7ms        3227B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.GlobalScripts.js
[0037] 12ms       2671B GET    200 /js/Sidebar.History.js
[0037] 14ms       1518B GET    200 /js/Toolbar.js
[0037] 13ms        12KB GET    200 /js/Viewport.js
[0037] 11ms       1978B GET    200 /js/Viewport.Info.js
[0037] 12ms        921B GET    200 /js/Command.js
[0037] 9ms        1178B GET    200 /js/commands/AddObjectCommand.js
[0037] 10ms       2248B GET    200 /js/commands/RemoveObjectCommand.js
[0037] 8ms        2549B GET    200 /js/commands/MoveObjectCommand.js
[0037] 11ms       1891B GET    200 /js/commands/SetPositionCommand.js
[0037] 14ms       1885B GET    200 /js/commands/SetRotationCommand.js
[0037] 12ms       1803B GET    200 /js/commands/SetScaleCommand.js
[0037] 15ms       1764B GET    200 /js/commands/SetValueCommand.js
[0037] 16ms       1452B GET    200 /js/commands/SetUuidCommand.js
[0037] 11ms       1692B GET    200 /js/commands/SetColorCommand.js
[0037] 8ms        1967B GET    200 /js/commands/SetGeometryCommand.js
[0037] 16ms       1822B GET    200 /js/commands/SetGeometryValueCommand.js
[0037] 18ms       1710B GET    200 /js/commands/MultiCmdsCommand.js
[0037] 18ms       1527B GET    200 /js/commands/AddScriptCommand.js
[0037] 12ms       1669B GET    200 /js/commands/RemoveScriptCommand.js
[0037] 16ms       2336B GET    200 /js/commands/SetScriptValueCommand.js
[0037] 23ms       1750B GET    200 /js/commands/SetMaterialCommand.js
[0037] 28ms       1946B GET    200 /js/commands/SetMaterialValueCommand.js
[0037] 20ms       1774B GET    200 /js/commands/SetMaterialColorCommand.js
[0037] 14ms       2848B GET    200 /js/commands/SetMaterialMapCommand.js
[0037] 16ms       2131B GET    200 /js/commands/SetSceneCommand.js
[0037] 12ms       4190B GET    200 /js/libs/html2canvas.js
[0037] 8ms        1433B GET    200 /js/libs/three.html.js
[0037] 6ms         97KB GET    200 /js/libs/glslprep.min.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /
[0059] 1ms        2540B GET    200 /css/main.css
[0059] 0ms        3163B GET    200 /css/light.css
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/three.min.js
[0059] 0ms        1497B GET    200 /js/libs/system.min.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/react-lite.min.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /ui-builder/react/core.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/controls/EditorControls.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/controls/TransformControls.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/jszip.min.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/AMFLoader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/AWDLoader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/BabylonLoader.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/ColladaLoader2.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/FBXLoader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/KMZLoader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/MD2Loader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/OBJLoader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/PlayCanvasLoader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/PLYLoader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/STLLoader.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/TGALoader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/UTF8Loader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/VRMLLoader.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/VTKLoader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/ctm/lzma.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/ctm/ctm.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/ctm/CTMLoader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/loaders/deprecated/SceneLoader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/renderers/Projector.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/renderers/RaytracingRenderer.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/renderers/SoftwareRenderer.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/renderers/SVGRenderer.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/codemirror.css
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/theme/monokai.css
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/codemirror.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/mode/javascript.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/mode/glsl.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/esprima.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/jsonlint.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/glslprep.min.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/dialog.css
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/show-hint.css
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/tern.css
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/dialog.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/show-hint.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/codemirror/addon/tern.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/acorn/acorn.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/acorn/acorn_loose.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/acorn/walk.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/polyfill.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/signal.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/tern.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/def.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/comment.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/infer.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ternjs/doc_comment.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/tern-threejs/threejs.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/signals.min.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ui.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/ui.three.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /dgframe/index.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/app.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Player.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Script.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/effects/VREffect.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/controls/VRControls.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/controls/OrbitControls.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/vr/WebVR.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Storage.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Editor.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Config.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/History.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Loader.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.File.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.Edit.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.Add.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.Play.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.View.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.Help.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Menubar.Status.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Scene.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Project.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Data.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Settings.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Properties.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Object.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.Geometry.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.BufferGeometry.js
[0059] 2ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.Modifiers.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.BoxGeometry.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.CircleGeometry.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.CylinderGeometry.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.IcosahedronGeometry.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.PlaneGeometry.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.SphereGeometry.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.TorusGeometry.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.TorusKnotGeometry.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/geometries/TeapotBufferGeometry.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.TeapotBufferGeometry.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Geometry.LatheGeometry.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Material.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Animation.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.Script.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.GlobalScripts.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Sidebar.History.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/Toolbar.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Viewport.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Viewport.Info.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/Command.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/AddObjectCommand.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/RemoveObjectCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/MoveObjectCommand.js
[0059] 3ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetPositionCommand.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetRotationCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetScaleCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetValueCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetUuidCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetColorCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetGeometryCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetGeometryValueCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/MultiCmdsCommand.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/AddScriptCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/RemoveScriptCommand.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetScriptValueCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetMaterialCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetMaterialValueCommand.js
[0059] 2ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetMaterialColorCommand.js
[0059] 1ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetMaterialMapCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/commands/SetSceneCommand.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/html2canvas.js
[0059] 0ms           0B GET    304 /js/libs/three.html.js
[0060] 1ms        3163B GET    200 /css/light.css
```

Comment: same thing same port.non attention to what is in javascript file.

Comment: I think in first loading something registered in system so for times after that it could not change that.but which system .where and how we could change it is my question.